# how to get function to accepts argument as a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Think this is a simple question but just can' get my head around it;

So have these:

```
var students = ["Joseph", "Susan", "William", "Elizabeth"]
```

`var scores = [ [80, 70, 70, 100],
               [85, 80, 90, 90],
               [75, 70, 80, 75],
               [100, 90, 95, 85] ]`

```
var gradebook = {
Joseph: {
   testScores: scores[0]
},
Susan: {
    testScores: scores[1]
 },
William: {
   testScores: scores[2]
},
Elizabeth: {
   testScores: scores[3]
},
addScore: function(name, score) {
    gradebook[name]["testScores"].push(score);
 },
getAverage: function(name) {
    average(gradebook[name]["testScores"]);
  }
};

var average = function(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b }) / array.length;
};
```

Have 2 arrays, and gradebook object, want to call gradebook.getAverage("Joseph") and return the average. 
but this line `average(gradebook[name]["testScores"]);` in getAverage function I don't think is working.

When I put the code into node terminal and then do `gradebook.getAverage("Joseph");` i get undefined.

If I do `average(gradebook["Joseph"]["testScores"]` in the terminal I get the answer I want.

Hopefully this makes sense!
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value from the `getAverage` method:

```
getAverage: function(name) {
  return average(gradebook[name]["testScores"]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting `undefined` from the function call is that they are not returning any value. Change it to this:

```
addScore: function(name, score) {
    return gradebook[name]["testScores"].push(score);
 },
getAverage: function(name) {
    return average(gradebook[name]["testScores"]);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! have just been learning Ruby and now JS, so not used to using  returns